# cannot find symbol variable imageView2

Tags: android-studio

I am just starting with Android Studio.  I got some code from the web on how to ass a splash screen to my app, but it has compiling errors.  I could use some help.

the errors are:

error. can not find symbol variable imageView2

error. can not find symbol variable s_img

error. can not find symbol variable s_image_black

error. can not find symbol variable s_image_black

I know this is due to my lack of knowledge, but I am just starting and trying to use this example to learn. Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers
Paul

```
package org.quaestio.kotlinconvertedwebview;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.quaestio.kotlinconvertedwebview.MainActivity;

import java.util.Random;


public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

Thread splashTread;
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    int[] ids = new int[]{R.drawable.s_img,R.drawable.s_image_black, R.drawable.s_image_black2};
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int r= randomGenerator.nextInt(ids.length);
    this.imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(ids[r]));

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                // Splash screen pause time
                while (waited < 3500) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            }

        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}

}
```

activity_splashscreen below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#feffc3"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/lin_lay"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/splash"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_img" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should add those image files(`s_img`, `s_image_black`) in your drawable folder and check if `imageView2` exists on your `activity_splashscreen.xml` file.

Comment: post your xml file here so that we can understand your problem

Comment: Thank you I will

Comment: this is my activity_splashscreen.xml

Comment: Ok i figured out that you can not add to this site you have to edit. It's above. Thank you for your help.  Paul

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting an id wich don't correspond with the xml file. For example `imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);` you need to change imageView2 with your xml imageview id wich is "splash". For the pthers error you need to check that files in the drawable folder.

Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` in your xml has id `splash`, so in your code, instead of:

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

you should do

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splash);
```

Also, this line:

```
int[] ids = new int[]{R.drawable.s_img, R.drawable.s_image_black, R.drawable.s_image_black2};
```

assumes that in your `drawable` folder there exist all these drawables:

```
s_img, s_image_black, s_image_black2
```

but apparently they don't, so you have to copy or create them and put them in the `drawable` folder.

Comment: thank you.  I will try this latter as of now I have to go to my other job.  Will report latter when done.Paul